# Get All Primary Keys w/ Non-Unique Indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing, information-schema

How do I get all the primary keys from a MySql database with non-unique indexes through query?

Comment: A primary key is a unique index so what are you looking for?

Comment: @Namphibian Some of the tables have secondary non-integer primary keys with 'Normal' index type.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like XY problem but I'll answer anyway. You can use INFROMATION_SCHEMA for this:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.table_constraints
 WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA='yourdatabase' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY';
```

This will list all columns which are primary keys but not UNIQUE keys.